# Getting Namespace added based on Condition for XML using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces

I am trying with to add namespaces to xml based on a condition. But the condition is not working. Can someone please help.

Input XML:

```
                    <n0:MainTag xmlns:n0='http://abc123.com' xmlns:prx='urn:testing.com' xmlns:soap-env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
                    <header>M</header>
                    <Data>
                        <Child>623471568753</Child>

                    </Data>
                </n0:MainTag>
```

Output XML:

```
                    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                <ns0:MainTag xmlns:ns0="http://xyz987.com">
                    <header>M</header>
                    <Data>
                        <Child>623471568753</Child>
                    </Data>
                </n0:MainTag>
```

2nd Input:
Input XML:

```
                <n0:DifferentTag xmlns:n0='http://abc123.com' xmlns:prx='urn:testing.com' xmlns:soap-env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
                <header>M</header>
                <Datum>
                    <Child>Test123</Child>

                </Datum>
            </n0:DifferentTag>
```

Output XML:

```
                <n0:DifferentTag xmlns:ns0="http://QWR.com">
                <header>M</header>
                <Datum>
                    <Child>Test123</Child>

                </Datum>
            </n0:DifferentTag>
```

XSL Tried:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                                xmlns:ns0="http://xyz987.com">
<xsl:output encoding='UTF-8' indent='yes' method='xml'/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="MainTag">
    <xsl:element name="ns0:{local-name()}" namespace="http://xyz987.com">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="MainTag">
    <xsl:element name="ns0:{local-name()}" namespace="http://QWR.com">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*/*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Condition : To check the tag name in the source XML

Comment: Don't forget to add that XSL tried! Also, can you explain exactly what the "condition" is? Thank you!

Comment: I have added the XSLT code tried, but was not getting the required output. Also we expect different xmls(more than 2), so i have given just two input xmls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your input XML both `MainTag` and `DifferentTag` are in the "http://abc123.com", but you are taking that into account in your XSLT, so it is trying to match the tags in no namespace.

You need to declare the prefix in your XSLT, and use that in the match.

Also note, your current XSLT has two templates matching `MainTag`, when one should probably match `DifferentTag`.

Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:n0="http://abc123.com"
                              exclude-result-prefixes="n0">
<xsl:output encoding='UTF-8' indent='yes' method='xml'/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="n0:MainTag">
    <xsl:element name="ns0:{local-name()}" namespace="http://xyz987.com">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="n0:DifferentTag">
    <xsl:element name="ns0:{local-name()}" namespace="http://QWR.com">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*/*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT: If you really don't know the namespaces in the input XML, try this XSLT instead...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output encoding='UTF-8' indent='yes' method='xml'/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[local-name() = 'MainTag']">
    <xsl:element name="ns0:{local-name()}" namespace="http://xyz987.com">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[local-name() = 'DifferentTag']">
    <xsl:element name="ns0:{local-name()}" namespace="http://QWR.com">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*/*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: But is it possible without using the namespce "http://abc123.com" comes from Source XML since it may vary with XMLs because of the different source systems.

Comment: I've made an edit to my answer to show how you can do this.